# Why is my Form styling not working

Tags: html, css, forms

Doing freecodecamp's portfolio creation exercise.. Should be easy in theory but I have a minor issue that I can't figure out.

I want to get rid of the border and the outline (when focused on) of my contact-area form but it's not working.

Here's my codepen - https://codepen.io/illpill/pen/WRgoVo?editors=1100

```
input, textarea {
  color: #333 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666 !important;
  border-top: 0px !important;
  border-right: 0px !important;
  border-left: 0px !important;
  background-color: #e3e3e3 !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

That's the css is in question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you got rid of the outline but forgot the box-shadow and border.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

live demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjXPpy?editors=1100